# Eclipse, Maven and incorrect MANIFEST.MF file being used

Tags: eclipse, maven, manifest.mf

This time I have a problem with running my Web App project in Eclipse.

Whenever I'll commit my app to SVN, then build it and deploy using Jenkins to Tomcat container - the app runs fine, and the correct MANIFEST.MF is used.

But, when I want to debug it inside Eclipse (with Tomcat 8.5 container) - there is an deafult manifest file used instead of the one containing my custom properties from pom.xml.

I've defined few variables in pom.xml regarding the application name, version and so on. The manifest file is being generated in /target/generated-resources/m2e-wtp/webResources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. This file contain all of my custom properties.

But when I call

```
resources = getClass().getClassLoader()
                  .getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

The path returned is: /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. The file indeed exists, but is almost empty:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Class-Path:

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <!-- <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>-->
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                </manifest>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                        <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                        <App-Version>${build.version}</App-Version>
                        <Build-Number>${build.number}</Build-Number>
                        <SVN-Revision>${rev.number}</SVN-Revision>
                        <Sys-Name>${sys.name}</Sys-Name>
                        <Sys-Full-Name>${sys.full.name}</Sys-Full-Name>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!-- <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</packagingExcludes> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I've tried almost every suggestion I've googled so far and nothing works :(

Please help!

Thank you in advance
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Finally I've found a solution. It turned out that I just need to simply copy a generated MANIFEST.MF file from the genrated wtp output folder to my project META-INF.

During building on Jenkins - the file is getting ovewritten by the generated one anyway so it seems that this makes no harm to project.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with NetBeans & Maven Java Web app projects. Debug uses target/Project-version folder created in the package stage before the .war file is created. The .war has META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, created by archive called by maven-war-plugin during package, but it doesn't create the same in the target/Project-version. I need the manifest created there, or created earlier with the right values.